# Small vs Large and Large vs Small sql joins

Tags: sql, theory

This is a theoretical question. At the office we are having a discussing whether it is better to Select from a small table and join the bigger table to or select from the big table and join the small one to.

One says that irrespective of indexes, it will always be better to start on the small and join the big to.

The other says, start with the primary concern of the script and join other tables to.

As for indexes, that is a secondary concern which can be analyzed later. We did some quick in house testing with some tables, problem with our test is we have years of accumulated indexes on either of the tables. Our test showed that the indexes made it all a moot discussion because they would give the same result in the end. 0 sec vs 0 sec.

Comment: No need to worry, the dbms optimizer choses the fastest way (whatever you say.) Make the query clear to read and understand!

Comment: `from a join b` or `from b join a` doesn't matter - any decent DBMS nowadays will optimize that properly.